# xmpp/smack chat using facebook application scoped id

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xmpp, smack

I am trying to develop a facebook application so that it will retrieve user information and if i need i can raise chat with the user using xmpp/smack api using java.

I have succeeded in sending facebook chat using the original Id.

**For example:**

for the user facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx the original Id is "10000xxxxxxxxxx" .(As we can get that using graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxx) and we can rise chat with the user by :-10000xxxxxxxxx@chat.facebook.com

But the issue is, by using facebook app we cannot get the original Id of the user. From the facebook apps created after 30th April 2014 we cannot get the Original user Id from the facebook app's even though the user gave permission to access his original data.

**Refer to facebook documention:**

> developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading
>
> [
>   1. App-scoped User IDs
>
> Facebook will begin to issue app-scoped user IDs when people first log
>   into an instance of your app coded against v2.0 of the API. With
>   app-scoped IDs, the ID for the same user will be different between
>   apps.
>
> ]

So how to do chat with the facebook user using app scoped Id even though we get permission from the user to chat???

For the user "10000xxxxxxxxx" i get the app scoped ID "764965xxxxxxxxxx".

These are the JSON data which i get when user accepts my request for chatting.

```
{ "id": "7649xxxxxxx", "bio": "....", "email": "xxxxxxxxx\u0040gmail.com", "first_name": "xxxxxxxxxxx", "gender": "male", "last_name": "xxxxxxxx", "link": "facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/7649xxxxxxxx/", "locale": "en_US", "name": "xxxxxxxxxxx", "timezone": 5.5, "updated_time": "2014-06-07T06:49:04+0000", "verified": true }
```

Kindly do me the favour and give solutions for raising chat with app scoped ID's(any how I am not violating facebook terms, I am informing the user and with his permission i get user informations,).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog . Which say that chat have been deprecated in API v2.0

Comment: @WizKid But chat using original id (:-10000xxxxxxxxx@chat.facebook.com) with smack still works. Any how thanks.

Comment: If you use an old app that was created before 4/30/2014 it will continue to work until 4/30/2015. If you created a new app or use API v2.0 it will not work